# How to call the GetOrAdd method on a .NET ConcurrentDictionary in a thread-safe way?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, collections, thread-safety

I'm trying to have a collection of `keys` which .. if the key doesn't exist, then I need to `DoSomeMethod()` and then add the key to the collection.

Problem is, this needs to be able to handle multiple threads trying to add the same key, at the same time.

If two threads have the same key, then only one will do `DoSomeMethod()` while the other needs to wait.

I've looked at using a `ConcurrentDictionary` and `GetOrAdd` ([with the `Func(..)` param option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378677(v=vs.110).aspx)) method but that seems to both 'fire off' at the same time if the two threads have the same key. I thought that the implementation of `GetOrAdd` would be

- lock 'key'
- get `value` from `key`.
- if no `value` then do whatever .. and now set value.
- return `value`.
  ... and any other `key` hits will wait until the lock is done.

It feels like my custom method which the `GetOrAdd` method calls, isn't thread safe.

The MSDN docs also suggest this?

> Remarks
>   If you call `GetOrAdd` simultaneously on different threads, `addValueFactory` may be called multiple times, but its key/value pair might not be added to the dictionary for every call

---

Contrite example: I'm copy files from `source` to `destination`.

- When copying a `source` file, check the collection if we've tried to check-and-create the destination folder.
- If the collection doesn't have the `key` then check if the destination folder(s) do not exist ... and create it if it doesn't exist.
- Once the destination folder is created, store this folder name/path in the collection.
- Repeat for all files.

So in effect, we only create destination folders if we haven't already done it.

It's like i'm wanting to lock on a collection KEY ....

Comment: You have to combine "check" and "do" within the same lock. If one thread checks key and decides do something seconds thread can interrupt "do" and try to do the same. Do I understand the problem correctly or there is something else?

Comment: Nope - 2nd thread cannot interrupt but must wait.

Comment: I still don't get what the problem is. Why concurrent dictionary doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yea that is how GetOrAdd works. It does not guarantee that the value factory won't be called twice only that you are guaranteed to get the same value back on both threads. The issue with your suggested implementation is that it requires a lock at fairly high level (every time a key is checked) and it requires holding a lock while calling out to external code. The concurrent collections are "low lock" to maximize throughput in high contention scenarios. Calling out to external code while holding a lock is bad because it create the path for dead locks.

Comment: Can you use SemaphoreSlim optionally with timeout? You can check count on it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class OnceOnlyConcurrent<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>> _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Lazy<TValue>>();

    public TValue GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TValue> computation)
    {
        var result = _dictionary.AddOrUpdate(key, _ => new Lazy<TValue>(computation, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication), (_, v) => v);
        return result.Value;
    }
}
```

I guess I should describe this a bit.  Basically what happens here is that while `AddOrUpdate` will always call the `addValueFactory` delegate twice if two callers happen upon `AddOrUpdate` at the same time, both of these calls don't really do anything but return a `Lazy<T>` reference that wraps the computation.

Inside `AddOrUpdate`, both results will be captured, but one will be dropped.  Only a single instance of `Lazy<T>` will be returned to both callers of `AddOrUpdate`, so a single `Lazy<T>` will govern the computation being called.

Then, on the next line, when we ask for `.Value`, that will actually trigger the computation on one of the callers of this custom `GetOrAdd` and the other will block while the first computes - this is the functionality of the second argument to `Lazy<T>` (`LazyThreadSafteMode.ExecutionAndPublication`).  BTW, this is the default behavior of `Lazy<T>` so you don't really need the second argument - I just used it to be more clear in this post.

Of course, this code could also be written as an extension method, but unfortunately, you'd have to know to create a dictionary with `Lazy<T>` objects inside, so I think it's better as a wrapper class around `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: This is the solution I was going to write up, The only thing I would have done differently is `var result = _dictionary.GetOrAdd(key, _ => new Lazy<TValue>(computation));` to make it shorter.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need for `GetOrAdd`. A simple check on the path and the key existence is enough:

```
class FileWorker
{
    private object _sync;
    private IDictionary<string, Task> _destTasks;

    public FileWorker()
    {
        _sync = new object();
        _destTasks = new Dictionary<string, Task>();
    }

    public async Task Copy(IEnumerable<FileInfo> files, string destinationFolder)
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(files.Select(f => Copy(f, destinationFolder)));
    }

    private async Task CreateDestination(string path)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
        });
    }

    private Task Destination(string path)
    {
        lock(_sync)
        {
            if (!_destTasks.ContainsKey(path))
            {
                _destTasks[path] = CreateDestination(path);
            }
        }
        return _destTasks[path];
    }

    private async Task Copy(FileInfo file, string destinationFolder)
    {
        await Destination(destinationFolder).ContinueWith(task => file.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destinationFolder, file.Name), true));
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var file1 = new FileInfo("file1.tmp");
        using(var writer = file1.CreateText())
        {
            writer.WriteLine("file 1");
        }
        var file2 = new FileInfo("file2.tmp");
        using(var writer = file2.CreateText())
        {
            writer.WriteLine("file 2");
        }
        var worker = new FileWorker();
        worker.Copy(new[] { file1, file2 }, @"C:\temp").Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Destination(string path)` is called on two threads at the same time you will call `CreateDestination(string path)` twice which is what the OP is trying to avoid

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, did you mean ConcurrentDictionary.ContainsKey is not thread-safe?

Comment: No, `ConcurrentDictionary.ContainsKey` is thread safe, however the combination of `if(!_destTasks.ContainsKey(path))
        {
            _destTasks[path] = CreateDestination(path);
        }` is not. Because those two operations are not atomic it is possible to have two `ContainsKey(path)` checks happen at the same time and both return true causing two calls to `CreateDestination(path)` to happen. (this is the exact logic the existing `GetOrAdd` does that the OP did not want)

Comment: @Scott And that's exactly why I suggested to wrap both calls to any "Slim" locker. In this case you don't even need concurrent collections.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, I agree that it's possible that 2 ContainsKey checks happen at the same time because that's what I aimed to. 2 checks may happen the same time but only 1 task is returned. And that leads to only 1 CreateDestination is executed.

Comment: Oops, I've just thought about it again and realized that race condition may happen after the `ContainsKey` check. Thanks Scott. And like @YuriS said, that combination needs a `lock` statement.